# Query optimization ndbcluster + order by

Tags: mysql, best-practices, ndbcluster

I'm not really all too familiar with the ndbcluster storage engine of MySQL, but I've recently written an application that does some very simple queries. However, a co-worker of mine (who is now on vacation, or I'd ask him about it, of course) left a TODO in the comments next to what I thought to be a pretty harmless query.

The comment read *"TODO: Avoid sorting on PK when querying on MySQL cluster"*

Granted, there are some things I'm aware of when working on a cluster (like using less `JOIN`'s) but I gathered the index (and therefore the PK) lookups were effectively *O(1)* operations, so a simple `ORDER BY someID DESC` wouldn't hurt performance.
I've been looking around on google, but I can't quite find a definitive answer as to what this `ORDER BY` means on a cluster. I can make a few educated guesses, but still...

What's more, I can't really think what query I can use instead. Basically, I have a generic method that enables me to fetch the last *N* rows based on 1 or 2 values. The simplified version of the query looks something like this:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM db.tbl 
WHERE user_Id = ? 
  AND req_action = ? 
ORDER BY tbl_Id DESC
LIMIT 0,?; -- 0,1 is default, though
```

Most of the time, the limit, though is 0,1, so I came up with this alternative approach that enables me to *not* use the `ORDER BY` clause, but it reduces the flexibility of my method, rather significantly:

```
SELECT *
    FROM db.tbl
WHERE 
    tbl_Id = (
        SELECT MAX(tbl_ID)
            FROM db.tbl
        WHERE user_Id = ?
          AND req_action = ?);
```

But in that case, I'm always going to end up with *either* an empty resultset, or a single row.

My questions:

- Is it true that `ORDER BY` on the primary key is not advisable on a cluster
- if so, what alternative constructs should I be looking at to maintain the flexibility of my initial query, while sticking to *good practices* for cluster queries?

Things to keep in mind:

- The dataset I'm querying is certain to have hundreds of thousands, if not millions of rows.
- The table will be used heavily, both read and write operations, 30 RW/s is not exceptional
- I can write stored procedures, but we only use them as a last resort.
- An `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` of both queries would have me believe that the first (my initial query) is still preferable, but I ran it on a vagrant box, and just noticed the test tables use InnoDB storage engine, so I take it I can't trust those results :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I've found the answer to my own question, and thought I'd post it here in case anyone else would ever have the same basic question:

Given that a cluster shard the data across numerous nodes, there is no *real* guarantee that an `AUTO_INCREMENT` primary key will reflect the order in which records were added. Especially when dealing with multiple master replication.
[Details can be found here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-cluster-replication-issues.html)

In essence, the answer to my question boils down to this:
Each node is given a range of available increment-values for the next N inserts. However, you have no *real* say in which node will insert the next row, and thus you can't be absolutely sure that the next row to be inserted will receive the `MAX(pk_id_val) + 1` as a PK value.
A simple diagram to clarify:

```
 +------------+      +------------+
 |   Node 1   | <==> |   Node 2   |
 +------------+      +------------+
 |   PK 1-3   |      |   PK 4-6   | (Range of available increment vals)
 +------------+      +------------+
 INSERT INTO cluster_tbl (field) VALUES ('test');
 INSERT INTO cluster_tbl (field) VALUES ('test');
 INSERT INTO cluster_tbl (field) VALUES ('test');
```

If all three insert queries are sent to Node 1, then all is fine and dandy, and the PK's will be 1, 2 and 3 respectively. However, if the first query is sent to node 1, the second to Node 2, and the third back to node 1 again, then the PK's will be 1, 4 and 2 respectively.
In which chase a `SELECT * FROM cluster_tbl ORDER BY pk_field DESC LIMIT 0,1;` query will serve up the *second* row that was inserted, and not the third.

A possible solution: create an index on an `inserted` field, defined as follows:

```
`insert` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

And order the query by descending timestamp values:

```
SELECT *
FROM cluster_tbl
ORDER BY insert DESC
LIMIT 0,1;
```

That, for me at least, did the trick